# How to add several identical child in a Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have a mobile game with several systems to have money (transaction or via an offer wall).

Players can choose between 3 types of "Gold coins" pack, and therefore obviously that they can request the same pack several times if they have the necessary number of pieces.

But I have a problem in my code:

```
public void mediumPack(String emailMP) {
        
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTime(date);
     Date previousDate = calendar.getTime();

     String dateString = dateFormat.format(previousDate);
        
      HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("amount", 5000);
        map.put("email", emailMP);
        map.put("date", dateString);
        map.put("status", MPStatus);
        
        DatabaseReference referenceMP = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("demandMP").child(user.getUid());
        
        referenceMP.child("Medium Pack")
            .setValue(map)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Toast.makeText(MediumPackActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        
                        finish();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MediumPackActivity.this, "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
        });
}
```

```
getMP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                    
            String emailMP = emailMediumPack.getText().toString();
                    
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emailMP)) {
     
                   emailMediumPack.setError("Invalid put mail");
                   return;
            }
                
            mediumPack(emailMP);
        }
});
```

So the child "demandMP" and uid are already created when creating an account.

In the uid I want to add the referenceMP, everything works but the problem is that after trying several times a single reference can be created (if I use another email address it will only modify the email in the "Medium Pack"

Is there a way to create multiple references?

Otherwise, I thought of creating a random ticket instead of the name "Medium Pack", considering this possibility someone could tell me how to create a random ticket that looks like this:

```
MP-XX...(18 chars)-5000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want generate unique child nodes under `Medium Pack` every time the code runs, call `push()` like this:

```
DatabaseReference referenceMP = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("demandMP").child(user.getUid());

referenceMP.child("Medium Pack")
    .push() // 
    .setValue(map)
    ...
```

Every time you call `push()` Firebase will generate a new unique ID, which you can then use to set the values.

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly well ! I have another quick question I cannot create a child with only the Uid in it I have to add something else like the email for example, is this normal?

Comment: FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Withdraw")
      .child(user.getUid()) // This does not work for example, I have to add for example the email and a setValue

Comment: There must always be a value, but it should be possible to set just a simple value like with `referenceMP.child("Medium Pack").push().setValue("test")`. If you're having a hard time making that work, I recommend posting a new question with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).